# Vue.js - Element UI - Use upload component without POST request triggering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using the upload component of Element UI. It unfortunately triggers a POST request as soon as a file is uploaded. What I'm aiming for is to push the files to an empty array which would be posted after with button.

**HTML**

```
// Element UI documentation says http-request overrides xhr behavior
// so I can use my own file request. In this case, I wanted to use a method
// though I'm not quite sure about this part?
<el-upload
     action="",
     :http-request="addAttachment",
     :on-remove="deleteAttachment",
     :file-list="attachments">
     <el-button size="mini" type="primary">Add file</el-button>
</el-upload>

// button that uploads the files here
```

**JS**

```
data() {
     attachments: []
},

methods: {
     addAttachment ( file, fileList ) {
          this.attachments.push( file );
     },

     deleteAttachment () {
          // removes from array
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried also setting `:auto-upload="false"`?

Comment: you don't know how embarrassed I look right now. thank you. that solved it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently, you also need to set the `auto-upload` prop to be `false`. Otherwise, it defaults to `true` and will automatically try to upload the file even if you've specified a function for the `http-request` prop.

In your case:

```
<el-upload
  action="",
  :http-request="addAttachment",
  :auto-upload="false"
  :on-remove="deleteAttachment",
  :file-list="attachments"
>
  <el-button size="mini" type="primary">Add file</el-button>
</el-upload>
```

[Here's the documentation for the component.](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload)

Comment: I ended up taking out `:http-request` and just kept the `:auto-upload`. I just need to show the files anyway. thanks!